# Javascript - Making an Array out of a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I'm trying to do something simple, but can't find the help I need :
I got a list, and I want to make an array out of it ;

Basically, my html's body is :

```
 <section>
    <ul id="idListe">
        <li>de l'amour</li>
        <li>de la joie</li>
        <li>des blablous</li>
        <li>des bisous</li>
        <li>des copains</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

My javascript is for now :

```
// console
var liste = document.querySelector('#idListe');
var collLi = liste.children;
var tablO = []; // dans ce tableau je cherche a mettre les valeurs de la liste ('de l\'amour', 'de la joie', 'des blablous', etc...)


// get properties, it's not what I want
for(var li in collLi) {
     tablO.push(li); // ajout a mon tableau (vide initialement)
     console.log(li); //  renvoie pas ce que je veux
 }
```

I got properties, not childs.
I think I've to interrogate the innerHTML of my

elements,
But can't find a proper way to do it ..

I think my issue is there :

```
var collLi = liste.children;
```

Can you make my search in the good direction ?
At this moment, I'm trying to use :
list.firstChild
list.nextSibling ..

Thanks !

This is a fiddle where my elements of work are :
https://jsfiddle.net/32o0rd7k/11/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get, an array of the `<li>` texts? eg `['de l'amour', 'de la joie', ...]`, is that it, or what?

Comment: Yeap, I could have been more explicit but that's the idea ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what `for-in` is for. It iterates the **property name** of the target, not the property values.

In reply to a question from CertainPerformance, you've [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649481/javascript-making-an-array-out-of-a-list/53649531?noredirect=1#comment94161470_53649481) that you wnat the *text* of the `li` items. From your original question, I thought you wanted the `li` elements themselves.

To do that, you have some options:

1. In ES2015+, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

   ```
   var tab10 = Array.from(collLi, li => li.textContent);
   ```

   `Array.from` can easily be polyfilled for pre-ES2015 browsers. It builds an array from any array-like object, calling the optional callback to allow it to map the values (in this case, from the element to its text content).
2. In ES5 and earlier, [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

   ```
   var tab10 = Array.prototype.map.call(collLi, function(li) {
       return li.textContent;
   });
   ```
3. In ES2015 or later on a modern browser where `NodeList` is iterable, spread notation plus `map` (but `Array.from` would be more efficient):

   ```
   var tab10 = [...collLi].map(li => li.textContent);
   ```
4. Or if you want to use a `for` loop, use `for` rather than `for-in`:

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < collLi.length; ++i) {
       tablO.push(collLi[i].textContent);
   }
   ```

I've used `textContent` above. If you need to support obsolete versions of IE (IE8 and earlier), you'll need to use optionally use `innerText` instead. So anywhere I have `li.textContent` above, you'd replace it with `li.textContent || li.innerText || ""`.

---

If you wanted the elements, not their text, then:

1. In ES2015+, `Array.from`:

   ```
   var tab10 = Array.from(collLi);
   ```

   `Array.from` can easily be polyfilled for pre-ES2015 browsers.
2. In ES5 and earlier, [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

   ```
   var tab10 = Array.prototype.slice.call(collLi);
   ```
3. In ES2015 or later on a modern browser where `NodeList` is iterable, spread notation:

   ```
   var tab10 = [...collLi];
   ```
4. Or if you want to use a `for` loop, use `for` rather than `for-in`:

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < collLi.length; ++i) {
       tablO.push(collLi[i]);
   }
   ```

---

Side note: This:

```
var liste = document.querySelector('#idListe');
var collLi = liste.children;
```

can be replaced with

```
var collLi = document.querySelectorAll('#idListe > *');
```

or in this specific case with

```
var collLi = document.querySelectorAll('#idListe > li');
```

Comment: @AlexisMASSON - No worries. I noticed your reply to CertainPerformance in the comments on the question, and updated the answer. If you want the *text* of the `li` elements, that's slightly different from my original understanding of what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the list items, convert to array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to array:

```js
const result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#idListe li'))
  .map(e => e.innerText);
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul id="idListe">
  <li>de l'amour</li>
  <li>de la joie</li>
  <li>des blablous</li>
  <li>des bisous</li>
  <li>des copains</li>
</ul>
```